# Create a branch from a specific version (from the previous changesets) on TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, team-explorer

How I can create a new branch but from a previous changesets in TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Visual Studio, when you go to create the branch, you can specify to branch from a specific changeset (the default is "Latest Version"):

[image]